# Vertical positioning inside anchor and button

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, alignment

```css
button, a {
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

button > div, a > div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <div class="buttonDiv"></div>
</button>

<a href="#">
  <div class="anchorDiv"></div>
</a>
```

We have buttons with icons in our project that render as button or anchor depending on props. We stumbled upon a problem with misalignment of button contents. In code snippet there is example.

Why does inner `div` aligns differently in button and anchor? How do I align contents of button vertically correctly? I could have just added `padding-top` but it does not seem right.

Comment: add display: table-cell; instead of display:inline-block; in button, a for making vertically middle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the reason you don't have a natural expected behaviour is that it's not valid HTML (as per HTML5) to include a `div` inside of a `button`. This means each browser may have a different way of rendering this.

As you said, you can do a workaround with padding or positioning easily to make it work as you desire, but it still won't be valid HTML. A possible workaround solution would be to reset paddings (to override default stylings) and vertically center content (without depending on the height of the element itself) on the anchor tag. https://jsfiddle.net/ne037nL7/

The button can only contain **phrasing content** which not only includes plain text but also `span`, `i`, and more (full list here https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20120329/content-models.html#phrasing-content).

Source: W3 https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20120329/the-button-element.html#the-button-element

Comment: Best answer so far, I would accept this if it contained full correct solution.

Comment: I've just added a workaround solution, let me know if that works as desired.

Comment: Yes, workaround works, but I would like html-valid solution :3

Comment: I misjudged, anchor is w3c-valid, only div inside button is w3c-invalid, I think I will replace it with span then.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```html
  <style>
            .main{
        display:table;
        }
            button, a {
              height: 30px;
              display: table-cell;
              border: 1px solid black;
              vertical-align: middle;
              padding:0 10px;
            }
            button {
              background: transparent;
              height: 32px;
              margin-right: 10px;
            }

            button > div, a > div {
              width: 30px;
              height: 10px;
              background-color: red;
            }
            </style>
          <div class="main">
            <button>
              <div class="buttonDiv"></div>
            </button>

            <a href="#">
              <div class="anchorDiv"></div>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
a{
display:table-cell ;
}
```

```css
button, a {
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
a{
display:table-cell ;
padding:0.5px 6px;
}
button > div, a > div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <div class="buttonDiv"></div>
</button>

<a href="#">
  <div class="anchorDiv"></div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
button {
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float:left;
}

a {
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}

button > div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}


a > div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <div class="buttonDiv"></div>
</button>

<a href="#">
  <div class="anchorDiv"></div>
</a>
```